# Form doesn't submit even after the fields are filled in ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The problem is I am trying to submit the form,but the form doesn't get submitted and shows the notification fill all the details. Earlier when I have not integrated with the ruby form tag it was working fine with regex validation. Below is the html Code of form:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => "home", :action => "update_order_details"}, :method => "post", :class => "order_details_form") do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id',nil, value: current_user %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'order_id', @order.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'txnid', @order.txnid %>
        <div class="contact_details">
            <div class="payment_details">
                <p>SHARE YOUR CONTACT DETAILS</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="input_name" id="fullName" pattern="^([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-Z]+$" title="Type only characters" name="name"  placeholder="FULL NAME" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="input_name" id="email" title="Eg: some@mail.com" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="input_name" id="mobileNumber" maxlength="10" pattern="^(\+\d{1,3}[- ]?)?\d{10}$" title="Enter 10 digit Valid Mobile Number" name="mobile" placeholder="MOBILE NUMBER" required/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

        <div class="terms_wrap">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="terms_condition" name="terms_condition" value="">
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pay_btn" style="display:none;">PAY</button>
<% end %>
```

JS CODE:

```
$('.pay_btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();


        $('.payment_details input').keyup(function() {
            var empty = false;
            $('.payment_details input').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    empty = true;
                }
            });
            if (empty) {
                $('.actions input').attr('disabled', true);
            } else {
                $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/update_order_details',
            data: $('.order_details_form input').serialize()
        }).complete(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.status === 200 ){
                $('.result').html(data.responseText);
                $('.payumoney').submit();
                setNotification('success', 'Proceeding To Payment!');
            }
            else{
                setNotification('error', 'Fill all details');
            }
        })
    // }
})

JS Code For Checkbox:
$("input[name='terms_condition']").on("change", function(){
        var isChecked = $(this).prop("checked"); 
        if(isChecked){
            $(".pay_btn").show(); 
        } else {
            $(".pay_btn").hide(); 
        }
    });
```

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: `complete(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { console.log(data)` ... and let us know what you see in your console.

Comment: Please include the controller code and the server logs for the Ajax call.  If the server is returning something other than 200, that's where it would be found.

Comment: @Sina I get this errors:

Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "NoMethodError at /update_order_details↵===========…n `<top (required)>'↵ - bin/rails:3:in `<main>'↵↵", status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error"}

Comment: look to your left the first thing you see, you use that code :)),you have a complete function in your code just add the console part lol :))

Comment: @madalinivascu yeah got it i already did..

Comment: @you have ruby problems with the controller responsible for /update_order_details

Comment: @madalinivascu yeah the problem got solved. But I have one question I have this regex validation in the input fields. Why that is not getting triggered on submit, if user enters wrong details??

Comment: from what i know regex is not fully developed on all the platforms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111701/discussion-between-preety-angel-and-madalin-ivascu).

Comment: Can anyone tell me one more thing in the form js if I remove e.preventDefault(); It is validating the only one input field and redirecting to payment page. How to stop redirecting the page with validation.

Comment: @PreetyAngel does your browser console show anything while you do that?

Comment: @PreetyAngel I think `<button type="submit"` should be `<button type="button"`.. try with that.

Comment: @techie_28 no it's not working the form is getting redirected to other page even if its empty

Comment: @PreetyAngel check the browser console..you may be having JS errors.